# Are DOM style calls limited by frequency?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, browser

I'm trying to resize an html element (flash object) but it doesn't seem to respond more than once per second?

Is this a limitation imposed by browsers (both IE7 and FF3 do this)?
Or should I be attempting to resize in a different/more efficient way?

```
function setHeightNow(height) { 

    if (document.getElementById) { 
     if (height > 0) { 
      var scaleItem = document.getElementById('application'); 
      scaleItem.style.height = height + 'px'; 
           }
    } 
   }
```

Comment: How are you calling `setHeightNow`? Are you doing it in a loop? You'll need to return control to the browser to get it to update on-screen.

Comment: I think this is flash-related. Normal elements do not behave this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling this function in a loop, as bobince mentioned in his/her comment, you should change it to a series of `setTimeout` calls (or `setInterval`) to give control back to the browser.

Something like this-

```
var i = INITIAL_VALUE;

(function() {
    setHeightNow(foo);
    if (i < FINAL_VALUE) {
        i++;
        setTimeout(arguments.callee, 0); //you can play around with the timeout.
    }
})();
```

Also

1. The `documents.getElementById` check is kind of useless because all browsers support it.
2. It would be wise to somehow take the `document.getElementById` call outside this repeating function if possible.

Comment: OP UPDATE:
This is only called once via a flash player ExternalInterface.call(), not currently in a loop of any kind.  The issue appears if I click more frequently than ~1 click/sec.  From my tests, the ExternalInterface.call() can reach the setHeightNow() method as often as possible, but "scaleItem.style.height = height + 'px';" isn't functioning.

Is it possible that the element I'm attempting to change, is locked or still being updated by the browser's rendering engine?  Is there a way to see if it is "ready" ?

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly not a defined limitation; we run an animation loop that is triggered 30 times/sec.  (Using a 33ms timeout.)  Mostly we move backgrounds around (animations) or adjust opacity (fade in/out) but sometimes we also re-size elements.

However, all of those elements are absolutely positioned, or in a fixed container, so it doesn't trigger a re-layout by the browser.  I suspect your problem is simply the cost of performing that re-layout, most of which would be down to the flash object itself.